# Is it possible to write a spec for infinite-loop issues using Rspec?, Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

Listen I've an interesting question here, the other day  I ran into an "infinite-loop" problem using Rspec, Rspec couldn't even go through the spec related to other methods inside the loop and  even the comp was almost crashing. Very funny.

I'd like to test my future loops (While-loop in this case) against **infinite loop-code.**
How I can test this while-loop and catch up this problem like this one and make the proper correction?

Thanks!

This is my code from other day:

```
 i = 0
      while i <= Video.all.count do
        if ( @sampler = Video.find_next_sampler(@samplers[-1].end_time, @samplers[-1].end_point) )
          @samplers << @sampler
        else
          flash[:error] = 'There is not any more match for this video-sampler'
        end
        i + 1  #Now Here is the bug!! IT should be: i += 1

      end
```

Comment: I think the only way you can test for this is by `timeout`, I think your problem is generally not solved. Compilers still cannot catch infinite loops.

Comment: How do you decide whether this loop is indeed infinite or you just didn't wait long enough for it to finish?

Comment: It is proved that there is no general solution to the halting problem.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev "you just didn't wait long enough for it to finish?" did u read my intro on how the issues escalates Rspec stopped working and so on? :)

Comment: @YoniGeek: oh, rspec didn't stop working. It was working just fine :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Hi Sergio! YEa it did big time, and suddenly the comp was also behaving funny. The Rspec stopped there where it was about to test things inside the loop. Rspec stopped a some point without given any information. This is why my interest for testing this issue

Comment: @YoniGeek: define "stopped working". Did it stop producing output? That's because it is busy running your loop.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev "Did it stop producing output? " Precisely! and then I waited and waited and I never got back anything unfortunately. It stuck there forever sort of to say. This is why my interest for testing this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'timeout'

it 'should not take too long' do
  Timeout.timeout(20) do
     ... blah ...
  end
end
```

Or even

```
# spec_helper.rb
require 'timeout'
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.around(:example, finite: true) do |example|
    Timeout.timeout(20) do
      example.run
    end 
  end
end

# my_spec.rb
it "should work really fast", finite: true do
  ... blah ...
end
```

Comment: That checks only the loop does not take too long to finish, not that is infinite.

Comment: Yea, I know. I'm trying to be a telepathist here and guess what the OP really needs. I suppose that he doesn't really want to check whether the loop is infinite. 20 seconds is a long enough time to consider the feature not working properly.

Comment: @DNNX HI there! I wanna check if my loop in this case (while-loop) is not looping infinitely, as u can see IT doest if I dont re-write the counter. right?

Comment: As sawa and @SergioTulentsev correctly said above, it is not possible to say whether a problem is looping infinitely or not. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem . You can only check if it runs no longer than X seconds.

Comment: @DNXX " it is not possible to say whether a problem is looping infinitely or not." Well I can tell that Rspec didn't go through all my specs, I couldn't keep testing and that's a problem. I found out on my own going through the code about this issue.

Comment: @DNNX HI there! I tried your first suggestion but it didnt work...any idea? thanks :https://gist.github.com/yonipacheko/d69f7277f54...

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example is doesn't make sense to run the loop more often that the total number of all videos in the database.

Therefore I would try something like this:

```
let(:videos_count) { Video.count }

before do 
  allow(Video).to receive(:find_next_sampler).and_call_original
end

it 'is not an infinite loop' do 
  except(Video).to receive(:find_next_sampler).at_most(videos_count).times
  # call your method
end
```

Comment: I wanna test yr idea...I'll come back to u then! thanks for yr interest

Comment: Hi there! I tried yr idea, but it's passing the spec when it shoudln't do it! ?

Comment: This means that you do not run into a infinite-loop (assuming that rspec's `at_most` match works correctly). Can you please post your `Video.find_next_sampler` method. I think the method actually causes the problem.

Comment: Hi there! Well it's not working unfortunately. Please look at this pasty, line 76 in the spec-part: http://pastie.org/9498329